# Create a dataset with everyday between start date and end date in R

Tags: r, loops, date

I want to create a dataset that contains everyday between 2 set dates without having to manually distinguish each day as a value.

```
start_date = 20181201

end_date = 20181210

date = (20181201, 20181202, 20181203, 20181204, 20181205, ..., 20181210)
```

Answer (score 3):

This would work:

```
df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2018-12-01"), as.Date("2018-12-10"), by = "day"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `seq` in base R...

```
start_date <- "20181201"

end_date <- "20181210"

format(seq(from=as.Date(start_date,"%Y%m%d"),
           to=as.Date(end_date,"%Y%m%d"),
           by=1),
       format="%Y%m%d")

 [1] "20181201" "20181202" "20181203" "20181204" "20181205" "20181206" "20181207" "20181208"
 [9] "20181209" "20181210"
```

The `format` terms are required to get the dates in the `YYYYMMDD` format that you specify.